# How can I set a variable of a user-defined type to an equivalent of in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, data-structures, null

I have a VBA function that performs a search, and needs to return an instance of a user-defined type if a match is found, otherwise it should return nothing. Unfortunately, I've found that a variable of a user-defined type cannot be set or compared to `Nothing`. Is there some equivalent that I can use?

Comment: Well you never have an instance of a UDT in the classical sense - its a non-object/reference type which is why a comparison to Nothing will not work.  To determine if a UDT is empty you need to examine one or more of its members and make a decision based on what you find. (You could add a specific flag member you set when you apply a value, add a byref success argument to the function or of course use a Class instead).

Comment: @AlexK.  Thanks, I'll use this approach!  I'm trying to get use to VBA, but I'm a C#.NET man, so I have a lot to learn! :-)

Comment: @AlexK.  Could you please copy your comment as an answer, so I can give credit where it's due! :-)

Comment: Good comment from @AlexK. One other way would be to return a Variant from your function, test with `IsEmpty()` and then cast to UDT..